# Ошибка запуска приложения: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error

Tags: java, tomcat

Привет.

Мне нужно стартануть веб приложение. Веб приложение работает на томкате. Я делаю это через менеджер.

```
http://server:8080/manager/
```

Приложение не стартует. Проблема - я не могу разобраться, почему оно не стартует - логи смотреть не получается, так как тут

```
apache-tomcat-7.0.23/logs/catalina.out
```

информации почти нету:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal SEVERE: Error
>   listenerStart

А как включить расширенный лог, я не знаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в томкате включить расширенные логи для приложения или как их смотреть?

Или может по-другому можно понять в чем дело?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот этот способ - http://itct.com.ua/oshibka-pri-zapuske-apache-tomcat-severe-error-listenerstart-i-severe-error-filterstart/, описана аналогичная ошибка.

Comment: пожалуйста, не оставляйте в качестве ответа лишь ссылку. ведь если она перестанет действовать, ваш ответ станет бесполезен. лучше написать в ответе суть, а ссылку привести в качестве дополнения.